# C# automatic property

Tags: c#, automatic-properties

Does the automatic property of C# 3.0 completely replace the filed?

I mean,I  can directly use the property instead of filed as property serves as private backing field.(sorry,I understand like that only).

```
int a;

public int A
{
  get;set;
 }
```

Comment: Please,keep your answer.Don't delete it.

Comment: generixs:  In the future, I would ask that you please don't just select the first correct answer you see.  It is frustrating for many of us when newbies do this because it tends to encourage fast answers and discourage possibly better answers that take longer to type, which defeats StackOverflow's primary purpose.

Comment: @ RayBurns . Sorry I will avoid it in future.Once again sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you access the property from code - whether inside or outside the class - it is always accessed as a property. In most cases, this is unimportant - but it *does* mean that you can't pass it by reference, which you would be able to do if it were a field.

The *only* piece of code which accesses the backing field directly (reflection aside) is the property itself.

It is a property, pure and simple. It isn't available as a field - it's available as a property. The C# compiler *doesn't* replace accesses to it with field accesses. Accesses to it are always property accesses. It may well be inlined by the *JIT* compiler of course, but that's nothing special. As far as the CLR is concerned it's just a normal property (which happens to have the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute applied to it).

But to answer your original question - yes, the automatic property means you don't need to declare the backing field yourself. Effectively, this:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

is translated into

```
private int <>Foo; // Or some other unspeakable name
public int Foo
{
    get { return <>Foo; }
    set { <>Foo = value; }
}
```

You *cannot* access the generated field directly in C# code, as it has an unspeakable name. You'll see it's present if you examine the type with reflection though - the CLR doesn't distinguish between an automatically implemented property and a "normal" one.

Comment: you mean to say when using property i can not do (ref A) if A were a property .right?

Comment: Please see my comment. "now" should have been "not" (otherwise the bit about reflection is a bit redundant).

Comment: Normally i have seen the notation Foo<int> ... But what does  private int<> Foo means? I mean angle bracket after int (i.e) int<> and <>Foo ..?

Comment: It's the name of the field: `<>Foo`. The C# compiler deliberately uses angle brackets to make the name "unspeakable" - i.e. one that isn't actually valid in C#, but is fine for the CLR. This means there's guaranteed not to be a collision with a "normal" member, and you won't be able to access it in code. The exact name is implementation-specific though - don't count on it being called `<>` followed by the property name. (I haven't even checked whether it happens to do that now - but it'll be something like that.)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the automatic property has its own holding field.

When you define an automatic property, the compiler will create the necessary backing field. It is not available as a field from regular code, but it is there and you can access it via reflection if you really need it.

Please see this guide for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: Sorry Nescio answered first.So i ticked his answer.

Comment: No problem. You pick the answer you prefer.

Comment: I disagree that it is "now available as a field" - that would suggest you could pass it by reference. It's a property, with its own private backing field that nothing else can access.

Comment: @Jon, you're right. Stupid typo. I meant to say "not available". Thanks.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

There is some compiler magic involved, such as with delegates, and so. You can see it as if the compiler takes charge of creating the necessary code that otherwise you would have to type in explicitly.